# Freeing a pointer of pointers in outside function

Tags: c, pointers

p1 pointer is used in other functions without any change. and when it is not needed any more `free_stuffs` function is called but when `free_stuffs` is called, I get double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)

```
char **someFunction(){
 const char ** p1 = (char **)malloc(total * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i <= total; i++){
        *(p1 + i) = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char) +1);
    }
    return p1;
}
void free_stuffs(char ** p1){
   for (int i = 0; i <= total; i++){
      free(p1[i]);
   }
   free(p1);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the caller of the functions.

Comment: Why use `*(p1 + i)` notation, when  `p1[i]` is available?  And the cast in `(char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char) +1)` is not necessary for `C` programming.  This would result in a simpler to read:  `p1[i] = malloc(len +1);`  (`sizeof char` is always `1` by definition.)

Comment: Where are `len` & `total` defined?

Comment: `i <= total` -> `i < total`. Don't deviate from the canonical for loop form `for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)` unless you have good reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating only `total` elements, but using `total+1` elements (`0` to `total`).

Allocate enough elements to fix the error.

```c
char **someFunction(){
 /* allocate total+1 elements instead of total */
 const char ** p1 = malloc((total + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i <= total; i++){
        *(p1 + i) = malloc(len * sizeof(char) +1);
    }
    return p1;
}
```

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).